# to_json returns string instead of json in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, string, rubygems

The following piece of code should return a json:

```
  @series = @series.map do |serie| {
    :name => serie.name,
    :id => serie.id
  }

  @series.to_json
```

It's return is the following:

```
"[{\"name\":\"Barra\",\"id\":3},{\"name\":\"Botafogo 1\",\"id\":1},{\"name\":\"Botafogo 2\",\"id\":2},{\"name\":\"Tijuca\",\"id\":4}]"
```

Why is it returning a string instead of a json?

'json' gem is both installed and required at the top of my .rb file

Comment: json is meant to be a string

Comment: I believe not. iOS JSON parser won't parse it, nor will my JSON prettifier plugin for Safari. I wonder maybe rails is not returning some content-type?

Comment: How are you trying to parse it? Code?

Comment: Yes, @Dogbert, I parse it in iOS. The JSON parser class raises an exception for the return is a plain string.

Comment: I think you are confused.  JSON is a language for serializing objects. So the natural representation of JSON itself is a string. IOS has some very slick classes for turning JSON stored in NSData objects into Foundation classes and back.  The NSData are basically strings that haven't been decoded with any locale convention.  See for example http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5 to see how all this fits together.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Gene. Actually I had this working before. I understand JSON is meant to be a string, but what I'm getting as response is a string in which the rest of the JSON is contained. This wasn't happening before. It started when I changed my development database from sqlite3 to postgresql. The problem is that now I can't parse this string. Nor can Swagger (API generator) or NSJSONSerialization in iOS.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've just resolved my problem. For some reason `as_json` does what I want rather than `to_json`. I didn't quite understand why. I'll update my answer if I ever find out.
That's strange, for `to_json` worked before I changed my development database form sqlite 3 to postgresql. But I don't think that might be the problem, because it was working nicely with Heroku's postgre database.

Comment: Because `to_json` returns a string, so quotes are escaped. `as_json` returns a hash.