# Ruby on rails : undefined method 'map' for #<String>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, forms

I am trying to create a rails form using  and  tag, but I want to generate options with a json file, because I want all the countries.
But I have this error :

```
undefined method `map' for #<String:0x007f871472e9b0>
```

Here is my application_helper.rb :

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def countries_for_select
    file = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'helpers', 'countries.json')).to_json
    countries = JSON.parse(file)
    countries.map {|c| [ c['country']['name'], v['country']['code'] ] }
  end
end
```

Here is my posts_controller.rb :

```
  def create
    countries_for_select
    @post = Post.new(posts_params)
    @post.user = current_user
    options_for_countries
    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Your post have been published"
      redirect_to post_show_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Here is the line in my _form.html.erb file :

```
<%= select_tag(:country, countries_for_select) %>
```

So I don't understand why it doesn't work,
Does someone could help me ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `file = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'helpers', 'countries.json')).to_json` line does not really return a JSON object, just a String. Have you tried printing `countries`? 
It could have something to do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134022/to-json-returns-string-instead-of-json-in-rails) post too.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `to_json`:

```
 File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'helpers', 'countries.json')).to_json
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

A little tip:

`Rails.root` has a method `join`:

```
Rails.root.join('app', 'helpers', 'countries.json')
```

Comment: I'd elaborate on that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev my english or anything else?

Comment: This one is better :)

Comment: Hi @Зелёный thank you for your answer now I have this line : file = File.read(Rails.root.join( 'app', 'helpers', 'countries.json')) and I have this error : 409: unexpected token at '{name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},
  {name: 'Åland Islands', code: 'AX'},
  {name: 'Albania', code: 'AL'},
  {name: 'Algeria', code: 'DZ'},
  {name: 'American Samoa', code: 'AS'},
  {name: 'AndorrA', code: 'AD'},
  {name: 'Angola', code: 'AO'}, ...... (all my json file) is that normal ?

Comment: @AntoninMrchd your json file is not valid. Check your file here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @AntoninMrchd: according to json spec, keys must be double-quoted. And strings too.

Comment: @Зелёный My json file was not valid, I try to find a valid json countries file and I will keep you in touch ! thank you !

Comment: @Зелёный Ok now I have this error .. undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I didnt see the json file, how I can know where is a problem?

Comment: @Зелёный Ok I put it in an answer of this post

Comment: @AntoninMrchd you should not, answers only for answer, also you try `c['country']['name']` but json file doenst have a key `country`, so I assume `c['name']` and `c['code']` should work.

Comment: @AntoninMrchd remove the json file from answer, that's not allowed on StackOverflow/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `.to_json` here

```
file = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'helpers', 'countries.json')).to_json
countries = JSON.parse(file)
```

`.to_json` is jsonifying objects (producing a json string from a complex object).

When it is applied to strings, it returns a string **which contains a string**.

```
"{foo: 1}".to_json # => "\"{foo: 1}\""
```

`File.read` already returns you valid json string (or so we assume), which you can later `JSON.parse`. But when you jsonify it one more time, it becomes another json object: **a string** (which, in turn, contains some json). This is what causes your error: strings don't have method `.map`.

Comment: @Зелёный: so that recursive serializers can work, I think :)

Comment: @Зелёный the reason is the same as `nil.to_json == 'null'`.